# Rename multiple file with same extension in a directory

Tags: bash

In Dir */home/test*:

```
a.244
b.244
c.244
d.244
```

I want to rename the files to just `a`, `b`, `c` , `d`.

I want remove `.244`.

I have tried `rename s/.244// /home/test/*.244`.

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debian, Ubuntu:

```
rename 's/\.244//' *.244
```

Fedora, other distros:

```
rename '.244' '' *.244
```

Comment: Thanks .. I was trying Debian, Ubunt version of rename into RHEL

Comment: Is this difference just due to a package version difference, or something else? If it's just a version difference, it would be more helpful for future readers, to give a version number instead of a distro.

Comment: @Robin It is some (another) breakage introduced by Debian, which they refuse to fix. They are two distinct renames. The one in Debian was originally `prename` as in Perl-rename, it was written by Larry Wall (Perl's author). The second one is the rename from util-linux-ng package, which in Debian it was renamed to `rename.ul`.

Answer (score 2):

Poor man's `rename` :)

```
regex="$1"
shift
for i
do
    echo "$i" | sed "$regex" | xargs -n1 -J % echo mv "$i" "%"
done
```

Use it for example (dry run):

```
./my_rename "s/\.244//" *.244
```

If the result was ok - remove the "echo" from the "echo mv" ;)